# Inhomogenous recurrence relations

Tags: co.combinatorics

Would someone be able to point me to a good resource explaining step by step the process for solving inhomogenous recurrence relations? (ie something of the form $ a_n = \sum{{b_i}{a_{n-i}}} + f(n)$ )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One standard method is generating functions. Set $A(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$
and $B(t)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i t^i$. Then
$$A(t)=a_0+B(t)A(t)+\sum_n f(n)t^n$$
so that
$$A(t)=(1-B(t))^{-1}\left(a_0+\sum_n f(n)t^n\right).$$
For an excellent text on generating functions, see Herb Wilf's
*generatingfunctionology*:
http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html .

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Wilf I also recommend Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's [Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) for these kinds of questions.  GKP has a lot of good material on, for example, techniques for estimating the growth rate of recurrences even when closed forms seem difficult to obtain.

Comment: Recommendation seconded!

Comment: Thirded. (Too bad isn't GKP isn't available online.)